# Rails Guides - Step 11 - Multi Model Form - MassAssignmentSecurity error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-model-forms

I'm very carefully following the RailsGuide and it's working beautifully, until Step 11.
Adding Tags via a MultiModel form.
Once I've added the code I get this error:

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#update
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tags_attributes

Application Trace:
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:65:in `block in update'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:64:in`update'

I've backed up and started over a few times to be certain it's not user error.
Can someone help me get past this step. I'm so close to done ! Then I can move on to Hartl's tutorial.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your fault!

The deployed Getting Started guide hasn't been updated for the Rails 3.2.3 default of

```
# in config/application.rb:

config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

The fix is to add this to your Post model:

```
# in app/models/post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tags_attributes
  ...
```

Incidentally, this whole section was removed from the source of the guide going forward, which you can find at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/getting_started.textile .

Comment: The stable version of the guide available in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html is the version available in the 3-2-stable branch in the rails repo. The guide in the master branch is currently being rewritten to be more beginner friendly and is available in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. It's a work in  progress and not 100% usable by beginners at this point in time.

Comment: Ahhhh ... I suspected as much. Also, that explains the mysterious extra line in my post.rb file that has attr_accessible for :content, :name, :title which I did not type in. Perhaps one of the generate or migrate steps in the guide added it ? Thank you much. I hope this will help other guide users.

Comment: I have 'config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true' in my application.rb and my pluralmodalname_attributes in my attr_accessible. However I still have that problem :/ ?